# Combine Spinner and AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, android-spinner, autocompletetextview

I am asking myself if it is possible, to combine a `Spinner` and a `AutoCompleteTextView`. Basically I want an `AutoCompleteTextView`, that shows all entries from `Array` when I click it.

Does anybody know how to do that?

Comment: item click is different from one to another

Comment: spinner is Give u pisition but AutoCompleteView Donot Give u Position also try

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this code:

```
 ArrayAdapter myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, YOUR_ARRAY);
    myAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(myAdapter );
```

Answer (score 54):

Just found out that this does exactly what I was asking for:

```
final AutoCompleteTextView textView;
    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names));

    textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtViewNames);
    textView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View arg0) {
            textView.showDropDown();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Very Good Job Man ! I was looking for exactly the same thing. I wish I could to +10. But what I found is when we type two characters then it shows the options in drop down. But still it is very very nice example. Thanks.

Comment: For resolve two character issue, add android:completionThreshold="1" to AutoCompleteTextView.